# My code is showing 'true' as output instead of 'False'

Tags: c++, recursion

So there is a question in Leetcode in which we need to tell whether two binary trees are identical or not. So my function is working correctly for the inputs [1,2,3] and [1,2,3]
but it is printing 'true' for the inputs [1,2] and [1,NULL,2] instead of printing 'false'. Please can anyone tell me what have i done wrong in this program.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.

 * struct TreeNode {

 *     int val;

 *     TreeNode *left;

 *     TreeNode *right;

 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}

 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}

 * enter code here    TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}

 * };

 */

class Solution
{

public:
    bool isSameTree(TreeNode *p, TreeNode *q)
    {
        if (p == NULL && q == NULL)
            return true;
        if (p != NULL && q != NULL)
        {
            if (p->val != q->val)
                return false;
            else
            {
                isSameTree(p->left, q->left);
                isSameTree(p->right, q->right);
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, step by step, one line at a time, what did you see?

Comment: I think you should use `return isSameTree(p->left, q->left) && isSameTree(p->right, q->right);` in the first `else` and remove `return true;` after that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're completely ignoring the results of those recursive calls. The point using recursion here is that two trees are the same if:

- Their values are the same AND
- Their respective children are the same.

You're testing the former, but never reaping the results of the latter. In reality, what you really should be trying to do is this:

```
class Solution
{
public:
    bool isSameTree(const TreeNode *p, const TreeNode *q)
    {
        if (p == q) // same actual tree or both NULL
            return true;

        if (p != NULL && q != NULL)
        {
            return p->val == q->val &&
                isSameTree(p->left, q->left) &&
                isSameTree(p->right, q->right);
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```